# Multiple SVGs on a page

Tags: javascript, svg

I have multiple SVGs on my page (they can be dynamically added using a plus or minus image as well). ie:

```
<img src="/svgs/mysvg.svg" id="svg1">
<img src="/svgs/mysvg.svg" id="svg2">
<img src="/svgs/mysvg.svg" id="svg3">
```

Inside mysvg.svg, there is a path element with the id #circle. When I am only display 1 svg on the page, I can use the following javascript to change the color of #circle:

```
$('#circle').css('fill', '#000000');
```

When I have multiple SVGs on a single page, how can I select which svg I want to change? ie:

```
var mysvg1 = $('#svg1');
mysvg1.find('#circle').css('fill', '#000000');
```

Comment: I think you are not telling us everything.  SVGs that are included via an `<img>` element are not part of the DOM and cannot be styled with CSS.  So your little jQuery snippet could not possibly work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var mysvg1 = $('#svg1');
mysvg1.find('[id="circle"]').css('fill', '#000000');
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you cannot do anything like that, document loaded in `<img>` is not a part of DOM of the host document.

But you can try to do something like this:

```
var img = document.getElementById("svg1");
// get the SVG document inside the img tag
var svgDoc = img.contentDocument;
// get that circle item by ID;
var svgItem = svgDoc.getElementById("circle");
// Set the fill attribute
    svgItem.setAttribute("fill", "#000000");
```

I am not sure if `img.contentDocument` would work on `<img>`, on `<object data="/svgs/mysvg.svg" type="image/svg+xml">` it works.